# Shopify GraphQL inaccurate response

Tags: graphql, shopify, liquid

I am using Shopify's GraphQL Tool to verify that my query is correct and it response exactly what I would expect to see [image: screenshot of shopify graphql tool]

Here is the code that I'm using on my storefront.

```
const query = `{
  products(first: 1, query: "sku:[DUMMY_SKU_HERE]") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        handle
        onlineStoreUrl
        title
        images(first: 1) {
          edges {
            node {
              transformedSrc(maxWidth: 100, maxHeight: 100)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`;

fetch("https://dummystore.myshopify.com/api/2020-07/graphql", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/graphql",
    "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": access_token,
  },
  body: query,
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

and here is the very incorrect response that I'm getting from Shopify. Not only is it incorrect, but no matter what SKU I pass in for my query it returns the exact same product data.

[image: screenshot of incorrect shopify response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the Admin GraphQL with the Storefront GraphQL.

The available Storefront GraphQL `query` params for the `products` are:

```
available_for_sale
created_at
product_type
tag
title
updated_at
variants.price
vendor
```

There is no SKU there.

Your screenshot seems to show the GraphiQL Shopify App that is tied to the Admin GraphQL API, not the Storefront GraphQL API.

That's why you get the same result, since the query is just ignored.

Comment: Where did you get that information from? I've been digging through the docs and they are all starting to blur together.

Comment: @CWSites from here: https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api/reference/queryroot

Comment: Thanks for the info, sucks that there isn't a way to do this but at least now I know why.